# awk: passing output to associative array

Tags: awk, zsh

Is it possible to pass awk output to an associative array ?

For instance, I have a test.csv file:

```
bill|gates|123
steve|jobs|234
elon|musk|345
```

If I do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} {print $1,$2,$3}' test.csv
```

I get:

```
bill gates 123
steve jobs 234
elon musk 345
```

Instead of this output, can I get the result in an associative array (`zsh`), like below?

```
typeset -A foo=(
  [bill gates]=123
  [steve jobs]=234
  [elon musk]=345
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```
typeset -a lines=("${(f)$(awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} {print $1,$2,$3}' test.csv)}")
typeset -a keys=("${(@)lines% *}")
typeset -a vals=("${(@)lines##* }")
typeset -A ary=(${keys:^vals})
```

Some of the pieces:

- `${(f)...}` - splits the output from `awk` at line breaks.
- `${...% *}` - removes everything from the last space to the end, leaving the first two fields for the key.  With the `(@)` and double-quotes, this is applied to each element in the `lines` array.
- `${...##* }` - removes everything up to the last space, leaving the value.
- `${...:^...}` - zips two arrays together, so we end up with `key1 val1 key2 val2 ...`.
- `typeset -A ...` - creates an associative array using the `k1 v1 k2 v2 ...` syntax.

---

Another version, using only `zsh`:

```
typeset -a lines=("${(f)$(<test.csv)}")
typeset -a keys=("${(@)"${(@)lines%|*}"//|/ }")
typeset -a vals=("${(@)lines##*|}")
typeset -A ary=(${keys:^vals})
```

This variant and the one below can handle spaces in the value, e.g. `j k|rowling|44 192 411` in the .csv file will create the element `['j k rowling']='44 192 411'`.

---

With some changes to the `awk` script, it can be done in a single line:

```
typeset -A ary=("${(@s:|:)${(f)"$(awk -F'|' '{print $1,$2"|"$3}' test.csv)"}}")
```

Comment: Awesome! Can I set the array name dynamically from another variable ? Something like `foo=bar;
typeset -A my_${foo}_array=([key1]="hello world" [key2]=baz)` ?

Comment: I was able to make a dynamic name work using `set` (not `typeset`) with a pre-declared associative array, based on @chepner's answer: `foo=bar; typeset -A my_$foo; set -A my_$foo ${keys:^vals}`. Note that the `set` assignment uses a slightly different syntax, without the `=(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Can you parse the data in `awk` and have the (awk) results re-parsed by the shell and stored in an array? Sure, but why not reduce the overhead and just have the shell directly parse the file and store in the array?

```
declare -A foo=()

while IFS='|' read -r fname lname val
do
    ndx="${fname} ${lname}"
    foo[${ndx}]="${val}"
done < test.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p foo
typeset -A foo=( ['bill gates']=123 ['elon musk']=345 ['steve jobs']=234 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk` to produce this output and then you can `eval` this output in `zsh` to create your associative array:

```sh
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {print "typeset -A foo=("}
{print "   [" $1, $2 "]=" $3} END {print ")"}' file.csv

typeset -A foo=(
   [bill gates]=123
   [steve jobs]=234
   [elon musk]=345
)
```